# Pi is not pi, but pi is pi....although pi is not pi?

Tags: r, interpreter, pi

So here is a question I have mostly out of curiosity.  I'm learning Pi with [Paul Teetor's *R Cookbook*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11161542-r-cookbook).  I was playing around with some of the commands, when I came across this oddity:

```
> v
[1] 3.000000 3.140000 4.000000 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593
> pi == v
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So checking what R considers pi to be,

```
> pi
[1] 3.141593
```

Apparently, R is giving me conflicting opinions on what pi is, or to show it more clearly I put the two into a matrix:

```
> v <- c(v, pi==v)
> mat <- matrix(v, 7, 2)
> mat
         [,1] [,2]
[1,] 3.000000    0
[2,] 3.140000    0
[3,] 4.000000    0
[4,] 3.141593    1
[5,] 3.141593    0
[6,] 3.141593    1
[7,] 3.141593    0
```

So apparently R considers pi to be 3.141593 on line 4, then not that on line 5, then back to 3.141593 on line 6, changing it's mind on 7 and so on.  Does anyone know what is the cause of this interpreter's indecisiveness?

Comment: You probably aren't displaying enough digits of precision.  Try displaying the *difference*, i.e. `(v - pi)` (or whatever the R syntax is for this).

Comment: It probably has to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Also, could it be that you hit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) problem, just the other way around? Try `isTRUE(all.equal())`.

Comment: @GSee Posting my thoughts 30 seconds earlier than me...How did you do that, man? I'm impressed ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you guys are correct.  I was assuming that the console output was what R saw pi as.  This was a very bad assumption.  The last four elements of v were entered as pi, 3.14159265359, (pi to 100 digits), 3.141593.  It's essentially seeing pi, smaller than pi, pi, smaller than pi.

Comment: For those that are interested it appears that R takes pi out to 15 digits as: 3.14159265358979 == pi is FALSE, but 3.141592653589793 == pi and beyond is TRUE.

Comment: No,  that's only true for the default builtin.  You can easily extend it with your own calculation, or via `gmp` .  More important, in the general case of comparing two floats, the answer is uncertain at the level of 2^(-16) or `.Machine.eps` .

Comment: Maybe you want to check "1 Falling into the Floating Point Trap" on the R Inferno... http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the same behaviour,

```
test <- function(digits, replications=10)
  c(representation = as.character(signif(pi, digits)), 
    equality = any(replicate(replications, pi == signif(pi, digits))))

t(sapply(1:16, test))

      representation     equality
 [1,] "3"                "FALSE" 
 [2,] "3.1"              "FALSE" 
 [3,] "3.14"             "FALSE" 
 [4,] "3.142"            "FALSE" 
 [5,] "3.1416"           "FALSE" 
 [6,] "3.14159"          "FALSE" 
 [7,] "3.141593"         "FALSE" 
 [8,] "3.1415927"        "FALSE" 
 [9,] "3.14159265"       "FALSE" 
[10,] "3.141592654"      "FALSE" 
[11,] "3.1415926536"     "FALSE" 
[12,] "3.14159265359"    "FALSE" 
[13,] "3.14159265359"    "FALSE" 
[14,] "3.1415926535898"  "FALSE" 
[15,] "3.14159265358979" "FALSE" 
[16,] "3.14159265358979" "TRUE"
```

only returns TRUE for 16 digits, which is understandable because of the finite precision of doubles.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't repeat 'pi' those 4 times.  I neglected to mention the important point which is that the last four elements of v are: pi, 3.14159265359, (pi to 100 digits), 3.141593.  So that's why I'm getting that behavior since R takes pi out to 15 digits beyond the decimal.